# Is there a way to determine "encoded table id" in Struts pagination?

Tags: java, pagination, struts1

I successfully implemented pagination for a list with displaytag in Struts(1.3).The links for each pages show as follows.

```
Page 3:
"http://localhost/...&d-49922-p=3&...".
```

Now I want to create a link to this page manually and for that I need to use "d-49922-p" parameter.
But I am not sure weather encoded table id(49922 in this case) will remain same as this all the time or changing or can we determine this value.
Any information on this highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
(new ParamEncoder("<Table Id>").encodeParameterName(TableTagParameters.PARAMETER_PAGE))
```

This will return the encoded table id.
Same method can be used to determine all other parameters under "TableTagParameters".